# how to check whether image is YUV or RGB format

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have downloaded a program, in which there are multiple classes. In that one of the function receives an image as parameter.  How can I check the Image received by that function in is in YUV format or RGB format using opencv ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Mat does not have such information. All you can get is depth and number of channels.